Build Failed with Exception AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.0-7396180-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon

I'm upgrading my application from flutter 2.5.0 to 3.19.0 and continuously getting the same error I have tried with multiple Gradle versions but nothing worked
I have tried different Gradle version and try to update Kotlin version and different methods like disabling it appt2 but that is also not working and increasing timeout of the aapt2 also not working

Firstly, error output should be pasted as text, delimited by triple-back-ticks, not as images. Secondly, it is most likely that there is some earlier output reporting that errors were occurring during the link. Can you find a log of what the actual linker error was?

Had this issue as well when upgrading to Flutter version 3.22.
Solved it by updating the Google Services plugin in <app-src>/android/build.gradle:
 buildscript {
     // ...

     dependencies {
         // ...
         classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2"
         // ...

     }
 }

or if you're using the new <app-src>/android/settings.gradle:
plugins {
    // ...
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    // ...
}

For me it seemed like google-services version 4.3.10 was not compatible with android sdk version 34.
